# Diophantine Equation Proof with Prime Exponent?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can you show that given a prime number p, if $x^{p-1} + y^{p-1} = z^{p-1}$ then $p \space | \space xyz$ ? I'm really looking for techniques to use because I have a couple more problems like this to solve. Is there any general way to approach Diophantine equations with prime exponents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use little Fermat. If $(a,p) \neq 1$, i.e., if $p$ doesn't divide $a$, then
$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$
Hence, if $p$ doesn't divide $x$ or $y$ or $z$, we have
$$x^{p-1} + y^{p-1} \equiv 2 \pmod{p} \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p} \equiv z^{p-1}$$